# How to open modal ?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I have a link in the top menu to add a new event.
When I am on the events list page, this link open a modal with the new event form.
Howether if I am on an other page, I would like this link (in the top menu) to redirect on this events list page with the modal new event form open.

Is it possible ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: everything is possible in this world. Just do it!

Comment: Thanks man, you're awesome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hash

link is like:

```
<a href="/costompagewithmodal#open">link to modal page</a>
```

in the /costompagewithmodal you show the div if the hash open exist

```
$(function(){
if(window.location.hash == '#open') {
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that it works !